# Fair Lottery when applicant equal to resources

Tags: c#, algorithm

Please consider this scenario:

There is 7 applicant and 7 place that they can placed on. I want to run an algorithm 7 times with this criteria: Every one of that applicant must be placed on one of that places **ONCE**. For example consider this first placement:

```
1
--
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

and in second turn if again A has chosen, A can not be placed on first place because its been already placed on first place in first turn:

```
1       2
-------------
A       B
B       A
C       F
D       G
E       C
F       D
G       E
```

in second turn I consider that B has choosen as second applicant and because he didn't place in 1th place so he can be placed on first place.

**I want to every choosen applicant in every turn can put in highest place that had not been previously and every one can just get in every place ONCE**

Can anyone help me to write such this algorithm.

Comment: For the sake of clarity can you provide order for 3. turn if A is chosen again?

Comment: @Lepijohnny : In turn 3 if A chosen, A can place in 3th place

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Bebakhshid , I don't understand what you mean :)

Comment: 7 items 7 places 7 iterations means the same result for each, just a different order. Does the order matter?

Comment: @Arian can item be in the same place two times if it is not selected?

Comment: @Lepijohnny Dear friend No every one can just get in every place ONCE

Comment: Create 7 combinations of the 7 places.  Shuffle.  Assign 1 to each person.

Comment: Its kinda like Sudoku. but in 7x7 size :D

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yes but with a little salt: Random number in white cells :D

Comment: So 0 effort on your side ? Where is the problem

Comment: Randomize list (first column). Shift each entry once (second column). Shift each entry once (third column)...repeat. Shuffle the list of lists.

Comment: @Sunshine but that's not really random .for example `A` always come after `C` (except at end of lists when circular shift or rotate is required).

Comment: His requirement don't state anything about the relative ordering inside the columns.  I agree the algorithm I wrote is not the best, but it technically fulfills his requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple algorithm should always work.

- Generate every possible `sequence` of the seven applicants. There are
  5040 of them.
- Choose one `sequence` at random and add it to the `chosen` list.
- Then repeat the following procedure six times:

  - Count the `sequence`s that don't conflict with any `sequence`s already in the `chosen` list.
  - Generate a random number between 1 and the count.
  - Find the non-conflicting `sequence` that corresponds to that random
    number.
  - Add that `sequence` to the `chosen` list.

Here's a typical output from the algorithm. The numbers on the right are the count of non-conflicting `sequence`s.

```
1 BDCEFGA  5040
2 CADGBFE  1854
3 GBADCEF   579
4 DGBFEAC   144
5 ECFAGDB    26
6 FEGBACD     4
7 AFECDBG     1
```

Will there always be a valid choice at the end? Yes, because after the first six choices, there's only one place left to put the `A`, one place for the `B`, etc. So there will always be exactly one choice for the 7th sequence. Proving that there will be valid choices for sequences 2 through 6 is left as an exercise for the reader.